# MySql: how to remove special characters from column in query

Tags: mysql

What i get value in php

```
    $subject = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', 'abc - 123');

// abc123
```

Is it possible to use preg_replace in my mysql query?

I want to something like this. want to compare like following

```
SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`subject` FROM `mail` where preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '',`subject`)=$subject
```

I know what i write above is not available. Still i want help. I didn't get proper answer.

I tried with function

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `removeExtraChar`(`str` VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
    NO SQL
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret CHAR(32) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END
```

and call it like

My table data

```
id   user_id   subject
----------------------
1      1        abc-123
2      1        xyz-234
3      2        new-post

SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`subject` FROM `mail` where  removeExtraChar(`subject`)=$subject
```

but this goes in infinite loop. Nothing executes
Note: I don't want to use extra mysql plugin.

Comment: Upgrade to MariaDB and use its `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Answer (score 1):

For similar purposes, you can also rely on a series and GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SET @str:='abc - 123';
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c SEPARATOR '')
FROM (
    SELECT MID(@str, id, 1) AS c FROM myseries
    WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND LENGTH(@str)
) a
WHERE c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]';
```

For this you could keep a `myseries` table for general use, it can be quickly created with 10,000 rows like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myseries (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO myseries
SELECT NULL FROM information_schema.columns, information_schema.columns c2 LIMIT 10000;
```

Or create one on the fly from any table large enough:

```
SET @str:='abc - 123';
SET @len:=LENGTH(@str);
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c SEPARATOR '')
FROM (
    SELECT MID(@str, id, 1) AS c
    FROM (
        SELECT @num:=@num+1 AS id
        FROM (SELECT @num:=0) num, yourtable
        WHERE @num<=@len
    ) myseries
) a
WHERE c REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is your query the problem here. If you used the function in the field `subject` if isnt indexed, this could take hours depending the amount of rows. You should call it in this way:

```
SELECT 
    `id`, `user_id`, `subject`
FROM `mail`
WHERE `subject` = removeExtraChar('abc - 123');
```

I tested your function and it worked:

```
mysql> SELECT removeExtraChar('abc - 123');
+------------------------------+
| removeExtraChar('abc - 123') |
+------------------------------+
| abc123                       |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**EDIT 1**

I've simulate your data example:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM  `mail`;
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | subject  |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 | abc-123  |
|  2 |       1 | xyz-234  |
|  3 |       2 | new-post |
+----+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The only complication with this is that it will not use any index on `subject` field because your use this function on it.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`subject` FROM `mail` where  removeExtraChar(`subject`)=removeExtraChar('abc - 123');
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mail  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**The query:**

```
mysql> SELECT `id`,`user_id`,`subject` FROM `mail` where  removeExtraChar(`subject`)=removeExtraChar('abc - 123');
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | subject |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 | abc-123 |
+----+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: thanks oNare.. but its take too much time. its loading. can't get any result